# alternating button on clicking event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey, it's all about Jquery. I am using two Div and a button, at a time only one div is shown. Suppose these are div:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

And button is:

```
<input type="button" value="show first" onClick="called a javascript();"/>
```

Only single div is shown i.e. `first`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#second").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Now on clicking button, I want to hide first div, show second and the `value` of button is changed to show second and if clicked again it revert back to previous state.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres' the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/vN88X/)**. Hope it helps.

html

```
<div id="first" style="display:none;">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="show first" />
```

script

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() === 'show first') {
        $('#first').show();
        $('#second').hide();
        $this.val('show second');
    } else {
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').show();
        $this.val('show first');
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no need to declare `$(this)` as variable. [Works just fine without it](http://jsfiddle.net/braiam/vN88X/1/).

Comment: yeah i know. for convention only.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function from jquery

Here's an example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gY7Rc/)

```
$(".toggleMe").click(function() {
   $(".toggleMe").toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: Hey i did this... but also I want to chage the value of the button.. which changes on single click first time only.. later it dont work

Comment: Ok, I updated the fiddle for you, it should help you to change the value. http://jsfiddle.net/gY7Rc/1/